# Custom login / redirect from WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on

I am looking to find a way for customers to log in to their customer account hosted at an external site but to be able to sign up and log in from our customer WordPress website.

e.g. Tom signs into his account using a login box at www.abc123.co.uk 
He is then redirected to his customer account panel hosted at www.def456.co.uk

I need customers to be able to do this, as opposed to logging into WordPress site and being taken to a page within the WordPress site.

Is it possible using SSO maybe? I hope someone can help me with solid advice on this.

Many thanks,

Richard.

Comment: Hello Be Internet DevOps, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be a bit more concise which domains are yours? Do you own abc123 and def456 or just one of them?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Login redirect plugin for custom redirect after login.
you can download from: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-login-redirect/

Comment: Thanks but this still only redirects users within WordPress whereas I need them to login on our own site and be automatically redirected and signed in to their customer control panel hosted externally.